# How do I switch to a Python log formatter I have defined in my logging.ini file?

Tags: python, python-logging

This is my logging.ini file:

```
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter,json

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=consoleHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=json
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_json]
class=pythonjsonlogger.jsonlogger.JsonFormatter
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s %(name)s - %(levelname)s:%(message)s
```

I want to switch the formatter via an environment variable, but this is not working (`AttributeError: 'RootLogger' object has no attribute 'setFormatter'`):

```
import logging.config

# Load logging config file
logging_config_file_path = path.join(
    path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), "logging.ini"
)
logging.config.fileConfig(logging_config_file_path)

# Override log settings via env vars
LOGLEVEL = os.environ.get("LOGLEVEL", "INFO").upper()
LOG_FORMATTER = os.environ.get("LOG_FORMATTER", "simpleFormatter").upper()
LOGLEVEL_NUMBER = logging.getLevelName(LOGLEVEL)
LOGLEVEL_DEBUG_NUMBER = 10
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(LOGLEVEL)
# setFormatter seems to want an object
logger.setFormatter(LOG_FORMATTER
```

I have all my settings defined in the ini file. How do I switch a formatter via an environment variable like I currently do for the log level?

### Edit

Perhaps I must be missing something obvious.

I tried passing arguments to the config, but it's not working and I can find almost no examples of how to use `defaults`:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(
    logging_config_file_path, defaults={"formatter": "simpleFormatter"}
)
```

In logging.ini

```
[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
# formatter=simpleFormatter
formatter='%(formatter)s'
```

Throws:

```
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: bad interpolation variable reference '%(formatter)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this an answer, but it's not a very good one.

I wound up just creating a separate log config file and switching like this:

```
LOG_CONFIG_PROFILE = os.environ.get("LOG_CONFIG_PROFILE", "logging_conf_local")
logging_config_file_path = path.join(
    path.dirname(path.abspath(__file__)), f"{LOG_CONFIG_PROFILE}.ini"
)
logging.config.fileConfig(logging_config_file_path)

logger = logging.getLogger()
```

Love to know if there is a better way or if this *is* the best way.